# Unexpected shift-selection in QListView with shared QItemSelectionModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have QListView with three elements: A, B, C. Select A in view. Then programmatically select C:

```
selectionModel.setCurrentIndex(idxC,  ItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate);
selectionModel.select(QItemSelection(idxC, idxC), QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
```

Now element C is selected and current in view, there is no any mark with A element. After that I shift + click element B and get A,B selection in view instead expected B,C.

Any ideas what to do with this?

This situation can be seen in qt Chart example (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-chart.html), where two list view share same selection model: click first view, click second view, shift+click first view to get unexpected result.

Comment: Have you tried simply clicking on `Item C` and then Shift+Click on `Item B`?

Comment: It works. In my situation list has hundred of itmes and it is common to select element from another view. It is strange to reselect already selected element to make group selection in list view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the behavior you described and some of the code review the best I can figure is that the `QAbstractItemView` does the selection on the mouse press event based on the previous mouse position vs. the currently Selected `index` in the model.

To fix that you might have to subclass `QListView` and reimplement `mousePressEvent`  function to change the behavior.  Conversely you can simply set the mouse position when you do the `Item C` selection.